# Reshaping long with multiple columns results in an error

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I've tried multiple threads and multiple attempts but I haven't been able to crack this yet so please forgive me if this is repetitive.

I have a data frame that looks like this but has way more columns (so hopefully the solution can be automated):

```
| id | Q1_wave1 | Q1_wave2 | Q1_wave3 | Q1_wave4 | Q2_wave1 | Q2_wave3 | Q3_wave1 | Q3_wave2 | Q3_wave3 |
|----|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
| 1  | 50       | 30       | 40       | 60       | Yes      | Yes      | 20       | 40       | 60       |
| 2  | 10       | 20       | 30       | 40       | No       | Yes      | 10       | 5        | 70       |
| 3  | 20       | 40       | 60       | 80       | Yes      | No       | 5        | 10       | 15       |
```

I would like my output to look like this:

```
| id | wave | Q1 | Q2  | Q3 |
|----|------|----|-----|----|
| 1  | 1    | 50 | Yes | 20 |
| 1  | 2    | 30 |     | 40 |
| 1  | 3    | 40 | Yes | 60 |
| 1  | 4    | 60 |     |    |
| 2  | 1    | 10 | No  | 10 |
| 2  | 2    | 20 |     | 5  |
| 2  | 3    | 30 | Yes | 70 |
| 2  | 4    | 40 |     |    |
| 3  | 1    | 20 | Yes | 5  |
| 3  | 2    | 40 |     | 10 |
| 3  | 3    | 60 | No  | 15 |
| 3  | 4    | 80 |     |    |
```

I tried reshape in this way:

```
df_long<-reshape(df_wide, 
    direction="long",
    varying=2:ncol(df_wide),
    idvar='id',
    timevar="wave",
    v.names=c("Q1","Q2","Q3"),
    sep="_")
```

and got the error:

```
length of 'v.names' does not evenly divide length of 'varying'
```

All the examples I've seen seem to work well when it's a single variable or the panel is balanced but I haven't been able to find something to work in this case. `pivot_longer()` has eluded me too. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Using `pivot_longer` :

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(df_wide, -id, 
                    names_to = c('.value', 'wave'), 
                    names_pattern = '(Q\\d+)_wave(\\d+)')

#      id wave     Q1 Q2       Q3
#   <int> <chr> <int> <chr> <int>
# 1     1 1        50 Yes      20
# 2     1 2        30 NA       40
# 3     1 3        40 Yes      60
# 4     1 4        60 NA       NA
# 5     2 1        10 No       10
# 6     2 2        20 NA        5
# 7     2 3        30 Yes      70
# 8     2 4        40 NA       NA
# 9     3 1        20 Yes       5
#10     3 2        40 NA       10
#11     3 3        60 No       15
#12     3 4        80 NA       NA
```

`names_pattern` is used to specify regex pattern to break the column names. This has to be in sync with `names_to`. `.value` is a special keyword indicating that part of the original column name would be in the final column. The first part `(Q\\d+)` specifies 'Q' followed by any number (here `Q1`, `Q2`, `Q3`) would be separate column and the number followed by `'wave_'` goes into `wave` column.

**data**

```
df_wide <- structure(list(id = 1:3, Q1_wave1 = c(50L, 10L, 20L),Q1_wave2 = c(30L,
20L, 40L), Q1_wave3 = c(40L, 30L, 60L), Q1_wave4 = c(60L, 40L, 
80L), Q2_wave1 = c("Yes", "No", "Yes"), Q2_wave3 = c("Yes", "Yes", 
"No"), Q3_wave1 = c(20L, 10L, 5L), Q3_wave2 = c(40L, 5L, 10L), 
    Q3_wave3 = c(60L, 70L, 15L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what is in the names_pattern argument? I didn't quite understand. My column names are slightly different from what I have here so I want to adapt it to my column names accordingly. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: I added some explanation about `names_pattern` and `names_to`. Hope that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `names_sep` with `_` in `pivot_longer` and if needed parse the numeric value with `parse_number`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
pivot_longer(df_wide, cols = -id, 
     names_to = c(".value", "wave"), names_sep = "_") %>%
    mutate(wave = readr::parse_number(wave))
```

-output

```html
# A tibble: 12 x 5
      id  wave    Q1 Q2       Q3
   <int> <dbl> <int> <chr> <int>
 1     1     1    50 Yes      20
 2     1     2    30 <NA>     40
 3     1     3    40 Yes      60
 4     1     4    60 <NA>     NA
 5     2     1    10 No       10
 6     2     2    20 <NA>      5
 7     2     3    30 Yes      70
 8     2     4    40 <NA>     NA
 9     3     1    20 Yes       5
10     3     2    40 <NA>     10
11     3     3    60 No       15
12     3     4    80 <NA>     NA
```

---

Or using `melt` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
 melt(setDT(df_wide), measure = patterns("^Q1", '^Q2', '^Q3'), 
    value.name = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3"), variable.name = 'wave')
```

#### data

```
df_wide <- structure(list(id = 1:3, Q1_wave1 = c(50L, 10L, 20L),Q1_wave2 = c(30L,
20L, 40L), Q1_wave3 = c(40L, 30L, 60L), Q1_wave4 = c(60L, 40L, 
80L), Q2_wave1 = c("Yes", "No", "Yes"), Q2_wave3 = c("Yes", "Yes", 
"No"), Q3_wave1 = c(20L, 10L, 5L), Q3_wave2 = c(40L, 5L, 10L), 
    Q3_wave3 = c(60L, 70L, 15L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```